# product of conjugates with same valuation

Tags: commutative-algebra, galois-theory, valuation-theory, ramification

Assume $L/K$ is a normal field extension and that $v$ is a valuation on $L$ (not necessarily discrete), with valuation ring $O_v$.

Let $\alpha\in O_v$, $\alpha\not\in K$, and let $\alpha'$ be a conjugate of $\alpha$ over $K$. Do we have $v(\alpha) = v(\alpha')$?   are there general conditions for this to happen? (e.g. v discrete?, v ultrametric? L complete with respect to $v$? other?)

---

**My try**:
Let us restrict ourselves to a Galois extension $L/K$ of Galois group $G$ (I think the general case reduces to this case anyway). Then $\alpha' = \sigma \alpha$ for some $\sigma \in G$.

We have $v(\alpha) = v(\sigma\alpha)$ iif $v((\sigma\alpha) / \alpha) = 0$, that is, $\sigma \alpha / \alpha$ is a unit of $O_v$.

We have $N_{L/K}(\sigma \alpha / \alpha) = N_{L/K}(\sigma \alpha)/N_{L/K}(\alpha) = 1$. So, it would suffice to prove that if $x\in O_v$ fulfills $N(x) = 1$, then $x$ is a unit of $O_v$.

Comment: In a Galois extension, the whole Galois group does not preserve the valuation in general. In fact, in general $v\circ \sigma$ is not only different from $v$, but is not even an equivalent valuation. You might want to look up the keywords "ramifiation" and "decomposition group".

Comment: The standard example is $v(a) = n$ if $a\in (2+i)^n,\not \in (2+i)^{n+1}$ on $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Then $v(2+i)=1,v(2-i)=0$.

Comment: @reuns. Indeed, thx. But maybe this property holds if K is complete with respect to the valuation (I have some reasons to think it does).

Comment: Assuming you want this *for all $\alpha$*, isn't this (by definition) equivalent to $O_v$ being a [Henselian ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henselian_ring)?

Comment: @Torsten Schoeneberg. Thx. Indeed, this is an equivalent definition of Henselian rings that is not sufficiently well known to the small mathematician. I have added it to Wikipedia. Why not making that comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property holds (for all $\alpha$ in all algebraic extensions $L \vert K$) if $O_v$ is a [Henselian ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henselian_ring). As per e.g. the source quotes in the comment, we also have the following converse: If $v$ extends uniquely this to all (normal, finite) algebraic extensions $L\vert K$, then $O_v$ must be Henselian. (Certainly it does not in general suffice to demand it for one specific extension. E.g. for $L=K$ the property is empty.)

Comment: I think this is not a bet, this follows from the known fact that in a normal extension of fields, all the valuations are conjugated (see https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/fjahn_01/franzi-notes.pdf, which is the best exposition on general valuation theory I've ever found online, only the past week unfortunately).